# Graphing sqrt function: not coming out properly

Tags: tikz-pgf, plot

I have been looking at other posts and have modified my code accordingly, but I still can't get it to work. I think there is an issue that has not been addressed in any of the posts that I have found. However, I don't know what the issue is, so I can't make a specific inquiry.

```
  \begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[xmax = 4,ymax = 3,samples = 50]
      \draw[black, smooth, variable=\x] plot (\x,{sqrt(1 - 4(x - \frac{1}{2})^2});
  \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!  If you go this way, the `x` must be a `\x`, i.e. `\draw[black, smooth, variable=\x] plot (\x,{sqrt(1 - 4*(\x - 1/2)^2});`, and you may want to add an appropriate domain. However, since you seem to use pgfplots, use `\addplot {sqrt(1-4*(x-1/2)^2)};`.

Comment: Thanks, marmot! Are you referring to the the x within the square root function?

Comment: I see. May you clarify what you mean by appropriate domain?

Comment: The build is saying the following: You can an axis with empty range (in the y direction)

Comment: I have to say, it doesn't come out very nicely. Would you help me make a graph (sorry to be pestering, haha)?

Answer (score 7):

OK, this is too long for a comment. There are several issues:

- You say `variable=\x` but one `x` does not have a backslash.
- You need to add multiplication signs.
- You cannot use `\frac` in an expression that is going to be parsed. `\frac` is used to *typeset* fractions.

Altogether, the expression should be (I guess) `{sqrt(1 - 4*(x - 1/2)^2}`. However, as you are using an `axis` environment, I think you are loading `pgfplots`, so I'd suggest

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[xmax = 4,ymax = 3,samples = 50]
  \addplot[black, smooth,domain=0:1] {sqrt(1 - 4*(x - 1/2)^2};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much marmot! I appreciate your help. :)

Comment: My very last question, which should be brief to answer, is how do I move the plot from the left margin of the pdf to the center of pdf?

Comment: @RafaelVergnaud This is due to `xmax = 4,ymax = 3,`. If you drop these, the plot is centered, and also if you make `xmin` and so on symmetric around the center.

Comment: Hey marmot! I mean on the pdf document. I did switch ymax to 4! Adding xmin did not center the plot of the pdf! It is still on the left hand margin of the pdf. If it's a hassle, I'll just leave it. It's no big deal!

Comment: @RafaelVergnaud  The above document is standalone, so I thought you want to center the curve. If you want to center the plot in a figure in an article document, say, you could use \centering.

Answer (score 3):

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[xmax=10,ymax=10, samples=1000]
  \addplot+[mark=none,samples=200,unbounded coords=jump] {sqrt(x)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I would suggest to do something like this
[image]